# Is HighCharts possible to combine polar chart with other chart?

Tags: highcharts

As you know, we shall set chart.polar to true to have a polar chart with HighChart. It seemed that polar chart is so different to other chart types, isn't it?

I've seen many other combination of different charts, but none of which could combine a polar chart.

Is it possible to combine a polar chart with a bar chart?

I guess it is possible since I believe HighCharts is powerful enough.

Comment: Polar chart is a column chart 'wrapped' around itself - very generic definition. A bar chat is a column chart with the axis flipped. What kind of chart are you wanting to combine with a polar chart?

Comment: @wergeld I understand polar chart is a wrapped bar char. But I still want to combine a polar chart with a bar chart because the 2 groups of data are suitable in the 2 different chart type.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: @wergeld I mean display the polar chart in the bottom right conner of a bar chart. for example, I want the pie chart in this example to be a polar chart. http://code.hcharts.cn/demos/hhhhDk

Comment: To do this you could create 2 separate charts. Does the polar chart need to be in the bar chart's render area?

Comment: @wergeld surely. Do you mean that I had better to find other solutions rather than HighCharts, for instance, with CSS to make the 2 charts overlapping?

Comment: Correct - the polar property is chart-wide.